# unpack(): Type n: not enough input, need 2, have 0 dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

Hi can anyone help me?

I'm new to laravel , I have a page need to print as PDF so i'm use dompdf

buat i get an error as below :

> unpack(): Type n: not enough input, need 2, have 0

i doesn't know what the problem is
can anybody help me please?

Comment: i already look that github but i'm not getting answer, basically i need to print view to pdf with the data but i just show me this error,

Comment: This is a very low level error message. It can be a bug from the lower level PDF library. It can also be a usage issue of the high level library / framework. Or it can be an issue with your own coding. There is simply too little information, here, for any outsiders to determine which.

Comment: I'd advice you to strip down your PDF generating code and see if you can get it work (e.g. to print something silly like "Hello World" in your PDF). Then you can add back code and see when it starts to break.

Comment: yup i already try it , but the error is still the same ,even a silly like"Hello world" ,so i'm just ditch out dompdf and using tcpdf , btw so much appreciate for spending time to answer my question . thank you so much , sincerely.

Comment: There's a known issue with php-font-lib that could be related: https://github.com/dompdf/php-font-lib/issues/47 have you tried using a different font?

Comment: Thank you @BrianS, yes i have try different font but it still the same and i try to add the font that they were say missing and no luck , Thank you

Comment: You should add some details about the HTML + CSS and the relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace back the error to its origin folder, you will notice that it is related to fonts.
In my blade file, I was referring to a font in the header without even using it and got the same error you have. I just deleted it and everything worked again.

Answer (score -1):

Try navigating into the config folder and edit the `dompdf.php` file, set
 `[ enable_remote => false ]`